# Android Wear step counter that does not use GPS for tracking

Tags: android

Most android wear running applications use gps for tracking and thus you need to move around for them to actually record distance covered, calories burnt etc. Are there any android applications that would work while on a treadmill?

Basically what I am looking for is android fitness application with android wear support, that accurately calculates steps calories etc and can be used with a treadmill. Most of the applications I found use GPS and distance covered to do those calculations. I want one that can work without that as on a treadmill you do not cover a real distance on a map.

I am ok with a paid application as long as it has a free demo to test it out

Comment: @Izzy added details on my question :)

Comment: Thanks, John! Much better :) So you basically want a Pebble #D (sorry, couldn't resist: but what you describe is exactly what my Pebble Time does as soon as Pebble Health is activated).